# independent execution of processes with semaphores

Tags: c, process, semaphore, shared

I have created a code for an unix project using semaphores.My code is this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "display.h"
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct  {
sem_t p1;
sem_t p2;
}SemPair ;

int main ( int argc,  char *argv[]) {  
SemPair *sem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED |MAP_ANONYMOUS , -1, 0);
int i=0; 
sem_init(&(sem->p1),1,0);
sem_init(&(sem->p2),1,0);

pid_t pid = fork();
if (!pid) 
{
    for( i=0;i<10;i++) {
        sem_wait(&(sem->p2));
        display("Hello world\n");
        sem_post(&(sem->p1)); }
    }
    else
     {
    for( i=0;i<10;i++) {

        sem_post(&(sem->p2));
        sem_wait(&(sem->p1));
        display("Goodnight world\n");
        sleep(1);}

}
sem_destroy(&(sem->p1));
sem_destroy(&(sem->p2));

return 0;
```

}

As you can  see my problem is that i dont want to get the display in order one by one but rather randomly.So my output is this.

```
Hello world
Goodnight world
Hello world
Goodnight world
Hello world
Goodnight world
....
```

Instead i want the processes to be not executed in order  so the output will be something like this :

```
  Hello world
  Hello world
  Hello world
   Goodnight world
   Hello world
  Goodnight world
  Goodnight world
  ....
```

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: Take a look at what semaphore is waiting when and for what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't happen the way you are using semaphores.

The whole problem of getting output mangled (and the reason you use semaphors to begin with) is that a process is interrupted in the middle of its writing.

Without semaphores, you have this:

1. process A starts printing "Hell"
2. process A is interrupted; other processes run
3. process B eventually get its share time and starts printing "Good"
4. process B is interrupted; other processes run
5. process A gets to finish writing "o world"

You know about this, of course. You can see how this causes the output to be mangled.

The point is how semaphores change this. By the time you get to point 3, process B will be blocked because of its call of `sem_wait` (btw, your "process B" is not handling the semaphore properly). When process A increases the the semaphore back to 1, `sem_post` will imediately unlock process B and let it continue before process A can go back to the beginning of the loop and run `sem_wait` again.

Comment: Maybe i was not clear enough.The thing i want to accomplish using semaphores is not to print lets say the first  display then the second then the first and so on 10 times.I want to display the whole line Hello world and the whole line goodnight world but in a random order.For example one time the first display then 3 times the second display then 2 times the first etc

Comment: No, you were clear enough! And I answered your question. When one process increments the semaphore back to 1, the other is immediately unblocked. So you'll always get "Hello world" and "Goodnight world" in sequence.

Comment: any ideas how i can accomplish the thing that i want with this code ? Or should i use a whole new different method instead . Thnaks for your help

Comment: The randomness that you get by two processes racing is pretty much lost when you use semaphores. So you would have to incorporate randomness back to your code intentionally. For instance, you could add a second semaphore just to control a protected memory region that says who should be the next process to print. Every time some process gets to print, they write a random value there.